# SQL Query Search with IN Statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Periodically I receive requests at work asking if I could tell the requester if certain stores in our company received over a certain amount of a specific item number.  I have a query that will easily allow me to drop in the list of 500 plus item numbers and spit out the stores that have (For Example) over 100 of that item.  The problem is that I then have to pull the data back into the excel file and transform it with vlookups against the stores to get my final answer.  Could someone tell me what function I would need to use drop in the ordered list of stores and item numbers to check for specific combinations?
For example, in a single row from the table I want to see if store 100 received more than 5 of item 1234.  I have 500 plus rows of pairs that I want to query for the "greater than 5" quantity.  There will never be non-unique combinations of Store and Item Number.  Each row is distinct.

**Example:**
**Store |  ItemNumber**
1  |  1234
2  |  4567
1 | 4567

EDIT: My company only gave me Read Only access to the data, so I am not sure if temp variables and tables are possible for me to use.

Comment: Try as I might, I don't follow.  Please provide a complete minimally verifiable example.  Provide tables and sample data involved along with expected results using that sample data.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How can a single store have more than a single itemnumber given you say each row is distinct?  Not completely understanding...

Comment: So if you already have a query that gives you the desired data; what is it that excel is doing for you?  or maybe.. `where (store, item) in ((123,'abc'),(1234,'def'),(456,'xyz'))`

Comment: Perhaps generate a derived table based on your store, itemnumber join this to your query? but all this depends on the RDBMS you're' using

Comment: Normally i drop in a list of item numbers, then export to excel for the remaining work.  That particular query is as follows:  'Select * from item.master where item IN (' ') AND SOH.master <0; ' I would like it to be something to the effect of 'Select * from item.master WHERE item IN (' ') AND store IN (' ') and SOH.master <0; ' This gives me combinations of store and item numbers.  The excel sheet is 2 columns, and each row is a distinct pair to query the table, but the lists get large, which is why I'd like to change the query.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a complicated `where` condition:

```
select t.*
from t
where (store = 1 and item = 1234 and quantity >= 5) or
      (store = 2 and item = 567 and quantity >= 10) or
      . . .
```

EDIT:

I see.  Your data structure is the data you want to pass in.  If it is only in the application, you can create a query such as:

```
select t.*
from t
where (store = 1 and item = 1234 and quantity >= 5) or
      (store = 2 and item = 567 and quantity >= 5) or
      . . . ;
```

Some databases use tuples, allowing:

```
select t.*
from t
where (store, item) in ((1, 1234) (2, 567), . . . ) and
      quantity >= 5;
```

Or, if the store/item pairs are already in the database:

```
select t.*
from t join
     storeitems si
     on t.store = si.store and t.item = si.item
where t.quantity >= 5;
```

Comment: @sgeddes . . . The question states "in a single row from the table I want to see if store 100 received more than 5 of item 1234"  and "Each row is distinct."  That makes me think that there is some sort of quantity column in the single row.  For some reason, the sample data does not have this column.

Comment: Fair enough, the `each row is distinct` comment is what is confusing me most here...  Having a `quantity` field could clear that up...

Comment: so this is hitting on the problem that I had.  normally i am given a list of specific pairs of examples.  500+ rows of 2 columns.  1 column is store, and one column is item number.  The request is always the same, to check for an amount of that specific item number in the specific store.  Normally i drop in item number list, export the information back to excel and translate it with vlookups against the original data to get my information.  That particular query is as follows:

Comment: I am querying for an item quantity in a specific store, for a specific item number.  But i am querying 500+ pairs of store/item number for quantity.

Comment: Is the quantity consistent or vary by combination?

Comment: The QTY (SOH field) is the information I am attempting to retrieve from the database, via the query, for every pair of store/item number represented as a row in a 2 column excel table (1 column is store, the other is item number).  I appreciate all the help from everyone, I am not trying to be difficult, but I am new to this, and I am trying to fix a process that takes a fair amount of time every day.

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER you could use `values` to generate a derived table and simply join

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1,1234),(2,4567)(1,4567)) AS Filter(Store,Item)
INNER JOIN (yourQuery) B
 on Filter.Store = B.Store
and Filter.Item = B.Item
WHERE B.QTY > 5
```

This could also be done using a union all and a subquery and join

Some RDBMS support a complex `in`:

```
where (Store, item) in ((1,1234),(2,4567),(1,4567)) and  QTY > 5
```

Comment: That is actually pretty much standard SQL, not SQL Server specific (will work with Postgres as well)

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was true across the board so I wanted to specify fr that specific instance I had tested.

Comment: The 'complex IN' is what I was researching, but how do you expand that for something as large as 500+ pairs?

Comment: excel use a formula to generate the (#,#), fill down copy paste to notepad then copy from notepad and paste into query with `where (Store, item) in (<paste>)`  but maybe I don't understand your question.  Though if quantity can vary per pair, I'd think you'd be better off using the values clause with the quantity and a join; or loading the data into a #temp table and then joining. on the off chance you exceed the maximum # of characters.